# what does string dot dot string give in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I am learning perl and I was trying something silly like

```
@months=('Jan'..'Dec');
print "The dates are: @months\n";
```

and I got lots of three letter words as output. Can someone please explain what is perl doing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perl is incrementing the string between the two ranges that you've specified.

Starting with `Jan` the next entry is `Jao` (as `o` follows `n`).  When we get to `Jaz` the next entry is `Jba`.

In your particular example the final entry is `Zzz` rather than `Dec` because `Dec` comes before `Jan` alphabetically and is, therefore, never reached.

See [Perl Range Operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) for more information.